# Difference between Box.com Created and Uploaded Webhooks

Tags: box-api

I am developing an app that uses Box.com Webhooks. I want an event to be fired everytime a new file is created, and thought that the Created webhook could help me out with it. However, irrespective of me adding a new file or uploading a new version of an existing file, only the Uploaded webhook gets fired. Could you please let me know what is the difference between Created and Uploaded webhooks of Box.com?

Answer (score 1):

Created webhooks are only fired for folder creation